# Sharepoint -How to Move/Copy folder to another location Using SOAP API copyIntoItems()

Tags: sharepoint-online, soap, move, java

I am trying to move/copy a folder from one location to another location it is giving me an error

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

but it is working fine with File.

I am using SOAP API   **copyIntoItems() function**

```
copyService.copyIntoItems(sourceUrl, destinationUrl, fieldInformationCollection, fileContent, hld,result);
```

but in this API we compulsory need to pass file content(data blob) but I have an empty folder that I have to copy/move

Comment: Your title says SharePoint 2013 - but the question is tagged as sharepoint-online! Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot copy folders from one location to another using `Copy.CopyIntoItems` - this method copies a document represented by a Byte array to one or more locations on a server. For more information, refer [Copy.CopyIntoItems method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/bb249887(v%3Doffice.15)).

A new utility class `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.MoveCopyUtil` is available on the latest version of the O365 **Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll**

`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.MoveCopyUtil` has the following functions:

```
public static void MoveFile(ClientRuntimeContext context, string srcUrl, string destUrl)
public static void CopyFile(ClientRuntimeContext context, string srcUrl, string destUrl)
public static void MoveFolder(ClientRuntimeContext context, string srcUrl, string destUrl)
public static void CopyFolder(ClientRuntimeContext context, string srcUrl, string destUrl)
```

for more information refer [MoveCopyUtil.CopyFolderByPath method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/mt844925(v%3Doffice.15))

Comment: thank you I'll check for the same

Comment: where I will get the  MoveCopyUtil? because I have to generate Stub from WSDL

Comment: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll check in this dll

Comment: I have tried but I didn't find any WDSL